# Crandall 1978: $m(2^{A_k}-3^k)<\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(3+\frac{1}{m})^{k-1}$?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

On page 1290 of [Crandall 1978](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-144/S0025-5718-1978-0480321-3/S0025-5718-1978-0480321-3.pdf), there is a line saying

> From Corollary (7.1) and Lemma (7.4) we have
> $$m(2^{A_k}-3^k)<\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(3+\frac{1}{m})^{k-1}$$

But looking at Corollary (7.1) we have
$$m(2^{A_k}-3^k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^{A_j}3^{k-1-j}$$

and looking at Lemma (7.4) we have
$$2^{A_j}\leq(3+\frac{1}{m})^{j}$$

So for me (7.1) and (7.4) would lead to
$$m(2^{A_k}-3^k)<\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(3+\frac{1}{m})^{j}3^{k-1-j}$$

but RHS is
$$3^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(1+\frac{1}{3m})^{j}=3^{k-1}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{3m})^{k}-1}{(1+\frac{1}{3m})-1}=m((3+\frac{1}{m})^{k}-3^k)$$

So it leads to
$$m(2^{A_k}-3^k)<m((3+\frac{1}{m})^{k}-3^k)$$
$$2^{A_k}<(3+\frac{1}{m})^{k}$$
or (7.4) again

Where does the first line came from? Am I not looking at the right place in those Lemma?

Comment: It is just $3 < 3+\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: oh!!! dumb of me. Thank you

Comment: Btw, what is in the first (cited) formula? There is a sum-sign, but the sum-index $j$ is not used. So it seems as if this is a little obfuscation - because the sum is nothing else as the $k$-mutiple of the parenthese : $k \cdot (3+1/m)^{(k-1)} $ and when $k \ge 4$ we can even use $ (3+1/m)^k $ in an in-equality... Or did I miss some sophisticated reason for that expression?

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, that's exactly what happens a few lines bellow ($k \cdot (3+1/m)^{(k-1)}$). I guess that's the whole point of replacing $3^{k-1-j}$ by $(3+\frac{1}{m})^{k-1-j}$